# Getting an error when trying to autofill input field from database based on a select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Script

```
$('#c1').change(function() {
                var serial = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url : "getserial.php",
                    data : {id:serial},
                    success :function(data) {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#c4').val(result.curr_serial);
                    }
                })
            })
```

HTML

```
<select name="c1" id="c1">
    <option value="">Select a type:</option>
    <option value="JC">JC - Jackets</option>
    <option value="PN">PN - Polo Neck</option>
    <option value="RN">RN - Round Neck</option>
</select>


<input type="text" class="form-control" name="c4" id="c4" maxlength="3">
```

PHP for getting serial number from the database.

```
require 'include/dbh.php';
$serial = $_REQUEST['c1'];
$sql = "Select `curr_serial` from serial where product='$serial'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
json_encode($row);
```

**The error that I'm getting is :**

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
>    at Object.success (addproduct.php:383)
> ```

I am unable to understand where I've made the mistake.

Comment: Do `return json_encode($row);` in your PHP script.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX success' callback doesn't receive any data. So `$.parseJSON()` fails.

1. In your javascript, `dataType: 'html'` should be `dataType: 'json'`
2. So you do not have to `$.parseJSON()`, and `data` will be an object in your `success()` callback function. See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (dataType section).
3. In your PHP, write `echo json_encode($row);` instead of just `json_encode($row);`.
4. Additionnaly, before to `echo`, apply header : `header('Content-Type: application/json');`